# Pandas - How to enforce two digits after decimal point using regex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` which has some values like this:

```
propvalue 
3000.2343
4000.4334554
```

That column is a string (str) type.

How can I leave only two decimals after point?

Desired:

```
propvalue 
3000.23
4000.43
```

I've researched and seems to be something like it:

```
df['propvalue'] = df['propvalue'].replace('\..*','',regex=True)
```

But above removes everything after point. I need leave two digits.

Comment: Do you need to round off at the 2nd decimal place or is truncation OK?  Meaning, is it ok that 2.99999999 truncates to 2.99 for a result?

Comment: And maybe before that...  It is usually best practice to just convert the whole column to numeric type and just set the display property to 2 decimal places (no info lost) unless you really want to drop the 3rd+ positions...  Would that be a better plan?

Comment: Truncation is OK. Already tried to convert, but it return the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float.

Comment: Ahhh, fix that first!  They should convert easily, and that is best practice.  use `pd.to_numeric(errors='coerce')` and assign the result to a new column.  Wherever the NaN's show up, those are the ones that need scrutiny (didn't convert).  Perhaps you have string characters or such.

Comment: If it's the regex you need help with, have you tried `.replace(r'\.(\d{,2}).*', '$1', regex=True)`?

Comment: The regex above replace with literal "$1" ie: 3000$1 and 4000$1

Comment: try `(?<=\d\.\d{2})\d*` as your regex

Comment: Why regex specifically? This seems like a string formatting task: `df['propvalue'] = df['propvalue'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)`

Comment: Why did you deleted your previous question when someone had already kindly provided an answer? Thats a bit rude.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['propvalue'] = df['propvalue'].astype(float).round(2)
```

other solution with Regex:

```
import re

df['propvalue'] = df['propvalue'].apply(lambda x: round(float(re.findall('\d+\.\d+', x)[0]), 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem specifically by regex you can apply the below code:

```
df['propvalue'] = df['propvalue'].replace(r'(?<=\d\.\d{2})\d*', '', regex=True)
```

Here I'm applying `positive lookbehind` to take only the second group within the selection.